# In Power Automate my Send an HTTP request to SharePoint using Patch method is not updating fields to null on SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

When I test my workflow manually and the result should be 3 fields should be null. The workflow comes back as successful.  I am including the workflow and List one item worked and the other item I changed from In use to Available didn't update the row.

[image: 1st Part of Workflow]

[image: 2nd Part of Workflow]

[image: 3rd Part of Workflow]

[image: Result of 2 tests]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by re-created the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint. Unfortunately, it doesn't like my JSON formatting I use for the form. I will remove the JSON.